Showing package specifiers
In my project, which I manage with uv, some transitive dependency is restricting numpy to numpy==2.0; even though the newest version is numpy=2.2.
Is there any convenient way to make uv tell me what the cause of this restriction in my dependency tree is?
I can get halfway there by uv tree --invert --package numpy, resulting in (redacted):
numpy v2.0.2
├── numba v0.60.0
|   └── my_main_project v0.1.0
├── matplotlib v3.9.3
└── scipy v1.14.1

However, this is forcing me to walk the respective packages by hand to find the restriction.
Much more convenient here (pip install pipdeptree):
$ pipdeptree -r -p numpy
numpy==2.0.2
├── numba==0.60.0 [requires: numpy>=1.22,<2.1]
│   └── my_main_project v0.1.0 [requires: numba>=0.60]
├── matplotlib==3.9.3 [requires: numpy>=1.23]
...
└── scipy==1.14.1 [requires: numpy>=1.23.5,<2.3]

Is there any way to produce this with native uv?

Currently this is not possible, as the necessary information is not stored in the lock file.
An alternative is to use uv pip tree with --show-version-specifiers:
$ uv pip tree --invert --package numpy --show-version-specifiers
numpy v2.0.2
├── contourpy v1.3.1 [requires: numpy >=1.23]
│   └── matplotlib v3.9.3 [requires: contourpy >=1.0.1]
├── matplotlib v3.9.3 [requires: numpy >=1.23]
├── numba v0.60.0 [requires: numpy >=1.22, <2.1]
└── scipy v1.14.1 [requires: numpy >=1.23.5, <2.3]

(uv pip tree is a reimplementation of pipdeptree.)
